# Why are the for loops skipped?

Tags: java, jvm

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long m = 0;
System.out.println("Going into the loop");

for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 3 == 0) {
            m = i + j;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Out of the loop");

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Time : " + (end - start));
System.out.println("m : " + m);
```

When I run the above code then value of "m" evaluated to 10000997 and the running time comes out to be 13321.

```
Going into the loop
Out of the loop
Time : 13321
m : 10000997
```

But when I comment the last S.O.P statement which prints the value of "m", then the running time comes out to be around 7.

```
Going into the loop
Out of the loop
Time : 7
```

So why does this happen? Are the for loops being skipped?

Comment: add print statements in your loop, you'll see for yourself whether they are skipped

Comment: @Stultuske that will change the behaviour... because then the loops can't be optimized away (because the do printing)

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe your compiler optimizes your code and removes the loop as it has become redundant when commenting out the last print statement.

Comment: @Nicktar it will change the time spent, but if we're speaking functional, no, it doesn't. It will, however, show very clearly whether or not the loops are skipped.

Comment: @Stultuske it will stop the JIT compiler from marking the whole loop as redundant after removing the redundant assignment to the m variable. So it will force the execution of the (most likely unrolled) loops that would otherwise be completely removed.

Comment: What JDK are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler optimizes your code and realizes that the variable m is in fact a dead store which can be removed. Then it realizes that the if doesn't do anything at all (after m was removed) and removed that too. Same goes for the ineer loop and then the outer loop.

Comment: Note: it's the JIT compiler doing that, not javac.

Comment: Further note that it doesn’t have to work that way literally. It could work in general by traversing a graph from the result values and perceivable side effects to the operations needed to get the necessary values, effectively skipping everything unneeded without even looking at it. This depends on how the internal IR is designed.

Comment: @Holger You are of course correct. The analyzing the optimization of the JRE is hard even with the output from the internal logs, without them it's educated guesswork at best and I intentionally skipped a lot of steps (loop unrolling, constant value propagation etc.) but for an example this small, I think the guess is reasonable close.